# How to execute stored procedure by select in instead of =

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

How to execute stored procedure by select in instead of = by vb.net and mssql stored procedure

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim objConn As SqlConnection
Dim objcmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds = New DataSet()

sSQL = "getinvoice"
objConn = utility.getconnect
objcmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, objConn)
objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
objcmd.Parameters.Add("@invoiceid", SqlDbType.VarChar)
objcmd.Parameters.Item("@invoiceid").Value = "1,5,13,18"    '<-- problem
da = New SqlDataAdapter(objcmd)
da.Fill(ds)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getinvoices]
@invoiceid varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
select * from invoice where invoiceid in @invoiceid     '<-- problem
END
```

Comment: Pass the `@invoiceid` as a table type, then just join to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use dynamic query. Change the procedure as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getinvoices]
    @invoiceid varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
    set @sql =' select * from invoice where invoiceid in  ( '+ @invoiceid     +')' 
    EXEC (@sql)
    END
```

Or Use a split function to split the values out into a table variable (there's a lot of split functions out there, quick search will throw one up).

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getinvoices] @invoiceid VARCHAR(50)
AS 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    invoice
        WHERE   invoiceid IN ( SELECT   *
                               FROM     dbo.splitstring(@invoiceid) )

    END
```

[Check here for Split string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Comment: there is no function dbo.splitstring exist is that needs to create by myself?How?

Comment: Yes you have to ..  Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: That's the worse kind of splitter you can use @ShijuShaji. Read this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/